# List files and show them in a menu with bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to use the files in a directory as options in a bash script. The user should be able to select one and then pass the name of the selected file into a variable. So far I can get the list of files, but after a few hours trying I can't figure out how to show them as options.

```
#!/bin/bash
prompt="Please select a file:"
options=( $(find -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0) )

PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do 

    case "$REPLY" in
    for i in "${options[@]}"
    do
    $i' ) echo "You picked $opt which is file $REPLY";;'
    done    
    $(( ${#options[@]}+1 )) ) echo "Goodbye!"; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;

    esac

done
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I do not think `case` is suitable here:

```
#!/bin/bash
prompt="Please select a file:"
options=( $(find -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0) )

PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit" ; do 
    if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        exit

    elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        echo  "You picked $opt which is file $REPLY"
        break

    else
        echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
    fi
done    

ls -ld "$opt"
```

Comment: I am getting an error using the above code.   /home/RepLoqt # sh -x  RevPrxyLogQuery.sh
' title='Reverse Proxy Log Query Tool (RepLoqt)
' prompt='Select the log file you want to query:
++ find ./logfiles -maxdepth 1 -print0
++ xargs -0
+ options='(./logfiles ./logfiles/log_18-44 ./logfiles/log_18-3)
' $'\r''Reverse Proxy Log Query Tool (RepLoqt)
 everse Proxy Log Query Tool (RepLoqt)
' PS3='Select the log file you want to query:
'evPrxyLogQuery.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `
'evPrxyLogQuery.sh: line 7: `select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit" ;

Comment: Never mind, for, some reason, because I had the .sh extension on the end of the file, it was giving me that error.  Once I removed the extension, it worked... I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Don't miss percol, fzy, smenu and friends. They'll happily take from stdin, present a user-friendly select menu with interactive filter, then pipe selected lines out again.

Comment: I feel like this answer could be greatly improved by giving more detail about each of the proposed alternatives and how each might be used to solve the asker's question.