# read a value from list and writing it in command line in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Need some help in reading the value from list and writing it as an input to the next command.

I need to write a shell script where it needs to have

1. `git tag -l`  --- which would list out all tags or version numbers like:

   ```
   v1.0
   v2.0
   v3.0
   v4.0
   ```
2. I need to read one of the value from the list output say, v3.0 and pass it to the next command
3. `read v3.0`
4. `git checkout <version number>`  example: `git checkout v3.0`

How do i achieve it in shell scripting? Pls help

Comment: This is quite broad. Do you need to run it for every line in `git tag -l` or for just one? Also, this is easy to google and find some examples. What did you try?

Comment: No. I dont need to run it for every line. It is just for one line. But the version    from "git tag -l" is dynamic. It keeps changing. Its the build version numbers.

Comment: So what't the point of running `git tag -l` if you just need one? How do you programmatically know which one you need to use?

Comment: I am writing a deployment script. For example, "git tag -l" would return 20 version numbers. I would want to deploy 3.0 build in to a server and not the latest build or all the build version numbers listed by "git tag -l". So i should be able to enter manually by using "read" command. that is $ read 3.0 and then i would like to add this version number 3.0 to the next comman in shell script which is "git checkout <version Number>"

Comment: OK so this not a one-liner but a full script.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your last comment, I think that @fedorqui is right. This question is a duplicate: you would like to build a menu and prompt the user. In your situation you should use `options=( $(git tag -l) )`.

The script at [List options in menu in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807845/list-files-and-show-them-in-a-menu-with-bash) becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

prompt="Please select a file:"
options=( $(git tag -l) )

PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit" ; do 
    if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        exit

    elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        echo  "You picked $opt which is file $REPLY"
        break

    else
        echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
    fi
done    

git checkout $opt
```

### ----

First answer for History.

The command you are looking for is `xargs`:

```
git tag -l | fgrep v3.0 | xargs -I xxx git checkout xxx
```

I have to warn you, if more than one tag contain `v3.0` then `git checkout` will be executed more than once.

Comment: Ok Thanks Jay. But one more question is, can i pass the buildNumber which v3.0 as a variable ??

Comment: @JamunaNandeesh check the new answer

Comment: Works great!! Thank you so much ...

Comment: copy/paste from @choroba answer...